# Converting factor values with levels to numeric in r

Tags: r, r-factor

I'm trying to convert factor values in R into numeric. I tried various methods but no matter what I do, I get the error "NAs introduced by coercion". Here is a sample code I run and the error I get:

```
> demand <- read.csv("file.csv" )
> demand[3,3]
[1] 5,185
25 Levels:  2/Jan/2011 3,370 4,339 4,465 4,549 4,676 4,767 4,844 5,055 5,139 5,185 5,265 5,350 5,434 ... dam

> a <- demand[3,3]
> as.numeric(as.character(a))
[1] NA
Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion
```

How can I get numeric values?

Comment: You have commas in your numbers, you also appear to have a date. you can get rid of the commas with gsub, but that won't help your first value (should you perhaps be skipping a line in your file?)

Comment: Please give some 10 observations of your data frame and make it a reproducible example.

Answer (score 2):

You should replace

```
as.numeric(as.character(a))
```

in your code with

```
as.numeric( gsub("[,]", "", as.character(a) ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

I got 2 comments here:

1. You are using probably files from East Europe Excel float notation (',' instead of '.').

To make it working well, use `read.csv2()` function.

2. The firs observation is probably the header? I guess the observations below are somehow connected via this date (2/Jan/2011). I will suggest to use `header=T` argument.

Summarizing:

Try `read.csv2("file.csv", head=T)`

If for any reasons you still need to change factors to numeric values, I suggest :

`f = as.factor(1:10)`

`as.numeric(f[f])`

Best,
Adii_